# How to display datagrid view row values in another form via cell click event without placing the show method inside the cell click event

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem displaying the value of data grid view selected row in another form.

Here is the situation, I have form1 which contains data grid view and I want to display the data grid view selected row value in text box in form2 via cell click event. My goal is to change the value of text box in form2 whenever I change the selected row.

This is my code:

```
private sub dgv_CellClick(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
         Dim row As DataGridViewRow
         row = Me.dgv_product.Rows(e.RowIndex)
         Dim frm As new Form2
         frm.TextBox1.Text = row.Cells("Column1").Value.ToString
         frm.show()
    End If
End Sub
```

I have a separate button for showing form2, and I want to change the code so that the form2 will not re-show every time I click a row and in dgv.

Comment: Explain what you want vs what happens better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, try to switch around the frm.Show() and frm.TextBox1.Text lines.  It might be trying to set the value before the form is created/shown. But a little more clarity in what you're trying to do would be good.